# Java Try With Resource Getting Error But Continued

Tags: java, sockets

Following here is my code

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port); InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // my code here
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I ran it as multithread, and some thread get these error

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoderI.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
```

According to that trace, error come from `BufferedReader.readLine`. As investigation, I manually connect to IP address used in that code, and found that actually the IP address is offline. So I assume it would be impossible to open socket to that IP address.

My question is, if we cannot open socket to that IP address, why my code continue running until `BufferedReader.readLine` instead of throwing Exception when trying open socket?

Comment: You're probably better off just having a single command in the `try (..)` with-resources, and having more nested `try`s if you need them when debugging

Comment: Good advice. So I can identify error more precisely. I'll do it.

Answer (score -1):

InputStream input = socket.getInputStream(); Here the input's value is null as the socket could not be made to the supplied host,port.

When you do  reader.readLine(), it uses underline stream InputStreamReader() to read the byte code and converts it into character stream.
Now the underlying stream(InputStreamReader) reads the byte stream from socket.
Before reading the data from underlying socket, the InputStreamReader class checks if the underlying socket is not null using method ensureOpen(), and if its null it throws IOException.

As in this case its null, and this gets triggered when reader.readLine() is executed.

Comment: The input's value is not null (whatever you mean with that). Calling `getInputStream()` on a closed or not connected socket throws an `IOException`, calling it on a socket that is `null` throws a `NullPointerException`. Your explanation cannot be correct.